# How to use Angular input fields email validation inside controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to validate a variable as email inside Angular controller.

```
var valid = $filter('email')($scope.email);
```

The email filter doesn't exists, generates "unknown provider error". What's the correct way to access email validation from inside the controller?

Thanks.

Later edit: don't put me to create a custom filter, it must be a way using angular validation.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a hidden input type email:

```
<input type="email" hidden id="emailValidator" required ng-model="x" />
```

Then in js set the value to that input and check validity:

```
var validator = $('#emailValidator')[0];
validator.value = "someemail@tovalidate.com";

return validator.checkValidity();
```

Also this documentation could be helpful: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: I'm not asking about form validation.

Comment: There is no form. The input field is a hack to solve this problem. I had exactly the same use case as you. I wanted to validate just a string and I used my solution to "hack" it that way instead of creating some cumbersome regex. Try it, it works.

Comment: I have a list of emails I need to evaluate from a textarea.

Comment: take your list of emails and loop through them and run the code I pasted on each of the email. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You could use form and prevent form submission by adding `ng-disabled` to the submit button:

```
<form name="form">
      <input type="email" ng-model="email" name="email" required/>
      <button type="submit"
        ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>

{{form.email.$valid}}
```

As the point of validation is to prevent submission and show error messages. I think it's enough to do it there instead of controllers where you handle your business logic.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjeYEBzgE0nrwnvyISvX?p=preview)

Comment: doesn't answer the question. How to access filter validation in controller?

Comment: @Alexandru Rada: the approach of using filter to do form validation is not recommended. That's why I suggested another approach

Comment: What makes you think I'm trying to do form validation? I'm trying to evaluate a string as email. And everybody answer is related to input fields.

Comment: @Alexandru Rada: If you want to do validation for user inputs before sending to server, I think using this approach is recommended. If you want to do validation for other cases (like loaded data from server), maybe we can just create a utility service with regex

Comment: Exactly that utility I'm looking for. With the help of angular built-in email filter. Now you got it right.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own filter:

```
angular.module(/**some module description here**/).
   filter('email',function(){
       var validateEmail = function(email) { 
            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
       }
       return function(input){
            return validateEmail(input); 
       };
   });
```

<sub>Regular expression is borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/1113426)</sub>

Comment: Why borrow from a SO question when you can just pick up the right expression from [the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.10/src/ng/directive/input.js#L27) ?

Comment: @svarog there are lots of ways for email's regexps. I have chosen the one from SO answer. Everybody is free to use their own or borrow from somewhere

Comment: you already get email regex validation out of the box (which you may already use in another part of your application), why add another and make implementation inconsistent ?

Comment: @svarog Yes, now it's native functionality, when I was writing my answer it was 2014 year :) . I am letting you to edit my answer with the following `However if you are using new angularjs, then you can use bla bla bla ...`. Or you can creat a new answer